# How do I insert new data to database every minute from api in python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-9.3

Hi am getting a weather data from an API every 10 minutes and am using python. I have managed to connect to the api and gets the data and gets the code to run every 10mins using thread. However the data that is being recorded every 10mins is the same without getting the new weather data. I will like it to have new rows inserted since the station updates new records every 10mins. Thanks in advance for your help.

below is my code.

```
timestr=datetime.now()
for data in retrieve_data():
    dashboard_data = data['dashboard_data']
    Dew_point = dashboard_data['Temperature'] - (100 - dashboard_data['Humidity']) / 5
    weather_list = [time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(dashboard_data['time_utc'])),
                    dashboard_data['Temperature'],
                    dashboard_data['Humidity'],
                    Dew_point,
                    dashboard_data['Pressure'],
                    dashboard_data['Noise'],
                    dashboard_data['CO2']
                    ]




def insert_weather_data(*arg):
    sql = (
        """INSERT INTO weather_data(time,temperature,
            humidity,
            dew_point,
            pressure,
            noise,
            CO2 ) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);
        """
    )

    conn = None
    weather_id = None

    # read database configuration
    params = config()
    # connect to postgres database
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    # create a new cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        # execute the insert statement
        cur.execute(sql,arg)
        conn.commit()
    except(Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
    finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()


def repeat_func_call():
    insert_weather_data(weather_list)

    threading.Timer(120, repeat_func_call, weather_list).start()

repeat_func_call()
```